# CSS Div with background image - how to allow for expansion of div on page?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, background-image

I wasn't sure how to word the question for this topic...sorry.

I'm just starting to learn CSS.

I have a `<div>` with a background image and there is text within the `<div>`. I read that choosing font sizes in **em** is a good choice because some people might require larger text sizes in their browsers. So setting the font-size with em would accommodate these types of users better.

But the problem with allowing the text to be resized, is that in many cases, the text within my `<div>` is going to go beyond the size of the background image and make the page look terrible and poorly designed.

Is there a way to use CSS and allow the background image to **'match'** or **'expand'** to accommodate to larger text size?

Comment: For my particular situation, I just found that if I sliced the background image into 3 separate images (top, middle, bottom), and then set them as backgrounds in 3 separate div's (vs. 1 div with 1 background), I could put the content into the middle div and 'that' div would then 'expand' to accommodate larger text. Note: font-size can be 'px' to leave size up to designer - or 'px' to accommodate the user. It works both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `width` of the `div` to the `img` `width` so that it never expands wider (beyond the image).

Of course, the enlarged text would force the `div` to grow height-wise.

You could also set the `background-img` to repeat (if the image allows for it), so that when the text expands, the image is repeated.

```
background-image:url('whatever.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;  

// x = horizontal, y = vertical
```

Comment: You gave me an idea, and I tried it out... I just had to split my image into 3 slices, and then use 3 div's instead of just 1. The text content goes in the middle div and with background-repeat it allows the div to 'grow' to fit the content.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting out, you might want to read http://na.isobar.com/standards/#_pixels_vs_ems wherein they say:

> We use the px unit of measurement to
>   define font size, because it offers
>   absolute control over text. We realize
>   that using the em unit for font sizing
>   used to be popular, to accommodate for
>   Internet Explorer 6 not resizing pixel
>   based text. However, all major
>   browsers (including IE7 and IE8) now
>   support text resizing of pixel units
>   and/or full-page zooming. Since IE6 is
>   largely considered deprecated, pixels
>   sizing is preferred. Additionally,
>   unit-less line-height is preferred
>   because it does not inherit a
>   percentage value of its parent
>   element, but instead is based on a
>   multiplier of the font-size.

**Correct:**

```
#selector {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5;  /*  13 * 1.5 = 19.5 ~ Rounds to 20px. */
}
```

**Incorrect:**

```
/*  Equivalent to 13px font-size and 20px line-height, but only if the browser default text size is 16px. */
#selector {
    font-size: 0.813em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative post...I appreciate it. So then, if I were to use 'px' instead of 'em', I understand that I would have more control over the text size (it being fixed), and I could leave the 'enlarging' process up to the browser via the Zoom feature. Thus, I wouldn't have to be concerned with the text going out of the bounds of my background image in the div. Does this all sound good? I just want to be sure I'm learning the right methods...

Comment: It sounds good to me.  You could probably test it at [http://jsFiddle.net] and prove one way or the other for your specific need.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the problem with using pixels (still) is that - although they can be resized by adjusting the browser controls - you are still forcing the visitor to make adjustments to use your page.  If you have the `font` set with `em` or `%`, the browser will take the visitor's settings and apply them.  But `px` renders as desired by the developer... leaving the visitor to manually make the changes.